# How to back from flutter module with data to native app ? I know how to send data from android to the flutter module! I just wanna the reverse

Tags: android, flutter, integration, flutter-module

This is the code to navigate:

```
 startActivity(
     FlutterActivity
       .withNewEngine()
       .initialRoute("/my_route")
       .build(this)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a map containing your data as an extra parameter of the invokeMethod().
Then you can receive it in your native code as call.argument("yourFieldName").

Flutter:

```
static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('yourChannelName');
_channel.invokeMethod('play', <String, dynamic>{
    'song': song.id,
    'volume': volume,
});
```

Java:

```
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
    switch (call.method) {
        case "play":
            final String song = call.argument("song");
            final double volume = call.argument("volume");
            break;
        [...]
```

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/invokeMethod.html)